# Is "Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS + LAMP" production-ready?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, lamp, ubuntu-server

Installing a **fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS** and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Is this configuration **production-ready** in terms of **security and stability**?

Comment: If you would elaborate a little, this could fit well into askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

No. Almost no system will be "production-ready" without configuring it properly according to your needs. Neither in terms of security nor stability/performance.